# Alert an array in javascript and make it copy/pasteable

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, alert

On JavaScript, I've got an array of multiple variables: **archive**. First, I would like the page to display this table by skipping rows at each value of the table. Second, I want the alert to be "copiable" by the user. I achieved the first part that looks like that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xtfh.png

However, it appears that the line :
`var archive = archive.join("\n")` blocks the copy feature of the alert.

My question is : is there a way to skip a line between values in an array **AND** makes it copiable by the user. (all of this in an alert javascript function).

Thanks in advance ! (if you need the code part of the *archive* array, let me know)

Comment: there's no copy feature of alert. The text in an alert is supposed to be selectable with the mouse and once selected it can be copied. the String.join() just returns a string as expected so there's nothing wrong there. Maybe you should share a static code that will produce an alert that won't be copiable as you said. Plus it's not clear what you mean by "skipping rows at each value of the table"

Comment: For your first sentence that's what I wanted to say.
However the array.join() makes that feature disable the "selectability" of the text. 
For your last sentence : I wanted to say : see the array elements each in a line.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't get my words. The message showed in an alert can be selected with the mouse pointer (but that's something in charge of your browser and your OS and it's not part of HTML or Javascript specifications). So the problem you are talking about doesn't exist unless you share a code that clearly shows it off. By the way alert() is not a solution that finds a place in production code.

Comment: I don't know how you came to the conclusion that array.join makes the feature to select such text disabled. It isn't true.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Thank you for the extra explanations.
I solved the problem by changing the browser (now on FireFox). If someone else has the same problem : notice that my conclusion seems true for the Opera browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.